# .htaccess not working with php includes

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying do use mod_rewrite at my .htaccess but isn't working.

my url is http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php?p=something
it should be http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/something

The file is in a subdirectory (gestor) in my host, where all the files are.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please add some more information to this, I'm having a hard time finding out what the issue really is.

Comment: What do you mean with `my url is`? Did you put that on your html page? And this `http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php?p=something` will not redirected because the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` fails here, and this `http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/something` seems to be working

Comment: READ THIS: I can see your directories http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/scripts/  secure your server remove `Options  +Indexes`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I removed it, thanks!

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions

my home page is http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php. When I redirect to some page I use the condition ?p=something but my url doesn't rewrite to /something.

Comment: @FluxCoder

my home page is http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php. When I redirect to some page I use the condition ?p=something but my url doesn't rewrite to /something.

Comment: @Gabriel Silva as i say above your index.php exists so your  rule wont work, try to move all files (e.g. index.php) into a subfolder and redirect into it. then  gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php is no more accessable and the redirect should work

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions my code now is:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /?p=$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

and my url is 
http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/?p=something

Still not working.

Comment: @Gabriel Silva   `When I redirect to some page I use the condition ?p=something but my url doesn't rewrite to /something` Your current .htacces wont work here.  As i ask above, what do you pastt on page. Because if you paste `http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/something` you can redirect to `http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php?p=something`. But you cant do that in both ways. it becomes the ping/pong effect then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one (if index.php is in the root folder `http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php`):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should work. Testet it here on my local maschine (No other server redirects or else, just a fresh xampp installation).

It redirect `http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/something` to `http://gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php?p=something` without changing the url in the browser.

And additional to the question in the comment.
This URL part `p=` should not be known be outside users!
Better use a long var here like `sadff34dngn4nil212ugn=`, so nobody can call the index.php with parameters directly from outside. You can't prevent that 100% but the redirect parameter `p=` is only for internal use.

But its just my opinion on that.

Hopefully that helps a little.

Find the right way to rome ;)

Comment: And if I have something/page/1, how it works?

my url is gestor.samfbas.com.br/?p=users&page=2
it should be gestor.samfbas.com.br/users/page/2

Comment: @Gabriel Silva Currently, if you use it like above, it will redirect to `index.php?p=something/page/1` the rest can be done and normally is done in PHP.

Comment: Yeah and `gestor.samfbas.com.br/users/page/2` becomes finally `gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php?p=users/page/2` and this is the first step to make an dynamic framework :)

Comment: May the problem is that you currently have this `gestor.samfbas.com.br/?p=users&page=2` generated by php  but you want  this `gestor.samfbas.com.br/users/page/2`, OK, but this is a new question for Stackoverflow. Tip `str_replace(array('=','&'),'/','?p=users&page=2')` and the remove the rest...

Comment: I don't get it =( gestor.samfbas.com.br/users/page/2 should redirect to gestor.samfbas.com.br/index.php?p=users&page=2

What should I do?

Comment: @Gabriel Silva  What should I do? Become an master in htaccess. Because you have to do a more complex REGEX in the RewriteRule like `([^/])/([^/])/([^/]) index.php?p=$1&$2=$3`. But thats nothing for comments. Make an question here on stackoverflow only for that redirect rule. Ask it like you did here in the comment, and only FLAG the question with htaccess apache redirect

Comment: Thanks, I will submit another question!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516329/htaccess-with-multi-parameters the new post. Thanks.