# htaccess with multi-parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect my links like this:

my href = `example.com/?p=users&page=2`
my URL should be = `example.com/users/page/2`

At this moment, my mod_rewrite is working with:

my href = `example.com/?p=users`
my URL = `example.com/users`

Here is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is change your `href` to your desired (canonical) URL. Otherwise (once implemented) you will end up redirecting _every_ request to the canonical URL (potentially slow for users, twice the server hit, etc.).

Comment: my href is already the canonical (users/page/2) but not working yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your complete .htaccess as this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# skip index.php from any rules below
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# handle /users/page/2 URI
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&$2=$3 [L,QSA]

# handle /users URI
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I Don't know what is going on but when i click at my href, I'm redirect to the correct page, but without my styles and other things...

my href example.com/user/page/2

Comment: To fix css/js/images path, you can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: Nope! I've tried `<base href="/">` and also `RewriteBase /` at my htaccess

Comment: Solved. At my `<link rel>` and `<script>` in my index I added a slash in the beggining of all directories! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

Try changing your `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(?:/page/(\d*))?$ index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

A slight caveat of this "one rule" approach is that a request for `example.com/users` will be rewritten to `index.php?p=users&page=`, ie. an empty `page` URL param.

`(.+?)` - The question mark in this subpattern makes the regex non-greedy, otherwise the *optional* second part of the regex will always be omitted.

Comment: Not working, actually... I think I'll let this the way it is. This thing is driving me nuts, Thanks, at all.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "page" path segment! I've updated my answer. (It would have previously handled `/users/2`, not `/users/page/2` - corrected.)